# some algebraic mistake (I guess) while doing integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

While I was doing integration. I got an example which looks like,

$$\int \frac{(\sin^{-1}x)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I just took $\sin^{-1}x=z$. At the last moment of integration. I got an equation something just like this (Here most of people are very professional that's why I am not writing all steps cause, the question will become very big).

$$\int z^2 dz$$
$$=\frac{z^3}{3}+c$$
$$=\frac{(\sin^{-1}x)^3}{3}+c$$

In my book, they have written.
$$\frac{z^3}{3}+c=\frac{1}{3}\cdot (\sin^{-1}x)^2+c$$

I guess power of $\sin^{-1}x$ should cube.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Note that they have $z^3$ in the previous step.

Comment: P.S. Did you really mean to put that picture behind a spoiler guard?